# Is it possible to use brightness filter only on text inside div?

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to use CSS brightness filter property only on text inside div? For example, here is HTML code and CSS code:

```
<div id="demo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" name="toggle" />
    <label for="toggle" id="toggle-label" >
        <div id="menuContainer">
            <div id="menuText">Menu</div>
            <div id="content">|||</div>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>

#demo{
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

#toggle {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
}
#menuContainer{
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background:rgba(0,0,255,0);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
    filter: brightness(100%);
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .4s ease;
    transition:all .4s ease;
}
#menuText{
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-right:20px;
    font-size:20px;
    float:left;
}
#content{
    font-weight:900;
    padding-top:11px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    font-size:25px;
    float:right;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
#menuContainer:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(150%);
    filter: brightness(150%);
}
#menuContainer:after{
    clear:both;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cqveLena/

In this case, brightness works when I for example change background of menuContainer to blue (but it also brightens entire div, along with text), but it doesn't work when I use for example rgba, to set background to blue and then hide it with alpha (it brightens text for a bit, but then it stops).

I also tried to use it on menuText and content separately, but it doesn't work either.

Is it possible to use brightness filter only on text? I don't have any more ideas.

Maybe I'm missing something? Maybe it could be done with javascript? I don't know how to work with jQuery yet.

Comment: CSS applies to **elements** and text is not an element. You could wrap the text in a `span` and apply the filter to that.

Comment: But the span still wouldn't ***just*** be the text. You could use inkscape and create an image instead. Harder to maintain for sure though.

Comment: isn't text brightness just text color?

Comment: If you simply want to lighten the background colour on hover just use alpha channel or white partially transparent overlay.

Comment: @Obsidian would be best to just change the background-color and the text color

Comment: @LorenzoCatalano Yes. This is what I am suggesting but with alpha channel you can create a lighter colour without having to work out the lighter colours hex value. Simply by increasing alpha.

Comment: @Paulie_D The text is wrapped inside div